# MultiArray descartar duplicados según condicion

Tags: php, array, loops

Tengo un array como este

```
$ratesData = [
    [1] => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 2
    ],
    [0] => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 1
    ],
    [2] => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 3
    ],
    [3] => [
        'id' => 2,
        'amount' => 2
    ]
]
```

Quiero mantener los ids duplicados con el menor amount, el resultado será como este

```
[
    [0] => [
       'id' => 1,
       'amount' => 1
    ],
    [1] => [
       'id' => 2,
       'amount' => 2
    ]
]
```

Tengo un código que funciona pero estaba buscando una forma mas elegante de conseguir el objetivo

```
    foreach($ratesData as $firstLoopKey => $firstLoopValue) {
        foreach($ratesData as $secondLoopKey => $secondLoopValue) {
            if($firstLoopValue['id'] === $secondLoopValue['id'] && $firstLoopKey != $secondLoopKey ) {
                if ($ratesData[$secondLoopKey]['total_amount'] > $ratesData[$firstLoopKey]['total_amount']) {
                    $deleteElements[] = $secondLoopKey;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($deleteElements)) {
        foreach ($deleteElements as $element) {
            unset($ratesData[$element]);
        }
    }

    $ratesData = array_values($ratesData);

    return $ratesData;
```

Gracias

Comment: por que la pregunta es ingles esto es un foro en español?

Comment: Perdon pensaba que estaba en inglés, ahora lo cambio

Comment: @user2755565 el sitio no es un foro, amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

No sé si será lo bastante elegante, pero utilizaría un array con ids únicos para almacenar el mínimo y recorrer el array una sola vez:

```
$mins= Array();
foreach ($ratesData as $index => $data){
    if (! array_key_exists ($data['id'], $mins)){
        $mins[$data['id']]= Array('id' => $data['id'], 'amount' => $data['amount'], 'index' => $index);
    } else {
        if ($data['amount'] < $mins[$data['id']]['amount']){
            unset($ratesData[$mins[$data['id']]['index']]);
            $mins[$data['id']]= Array('id' => $data['id'], 'amount' => $data['amount'], 'index' => $index);
        } else {
            unset($ratesData[$index]);
        }
    }
}
return $ratesData;
```